# SendGrid map dynamicTemplateData to the same template multiple times

Tags: sendgrid

I basically want to be able supply an array of objects to the dynamicTemplateData. When the template in Sendgrid receives this data, it should replicate the template within the email its creating for each object in the array. Is this currently possible, or would I need to send separate emails for each object?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

In a SendGrid dynamic template you use handlebars to render the data into the email. If you have an array of items you can [iterate through the array to render each of the object using the `#each` function](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#iterations).

For example, with the data

```json
{
  "user": {
    "orderHistory": [
      {
        "date": "2/1/2018",
        "item": "shoes"
      },
      {
        "date": "1/4/2017",
        "item": "hat"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can write a template like this:

```html
<ol>
  {{#each user.orderHistory}}
   <li>You ordered: {{this.item}} on: {{this.date}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ol>
```

And it will render:

```html
<ol>
  <li>You ordered: shoes on: 2/1/2018</li>
  <li>You ordered: hat on: 1/42017</li>
</ol>
```

There are more [examples in the documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#dynamic-content-creation).